# Does the Hasselblad X1D have a PC socket?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, hasselblad

Looking at the connections on the left side of the Hassy X1D I see:

[image]

- 2 SD-card slots,
- an HDMI connector,
- a USB connector,
- a microphone connector,
- and a headphone connector.

No PC socket? Doesn't the X1D have one? If it doesn't, can I use an adapter like the *Nikon AS-15 Sync Terminal Adapter*? (I understand Hasselblad uses a Nikon compatible hot shoe.)

---

*Image shamelessly stolen from [this web page](https://www.photigy.com/hasselblad-x1d-everything-your-need-know/)*

Comment: Wow, you have a Hasselblad ! Wow : )

Comment: @Janas: At this moment just an (expensive) dream (the picture is from the web)! But I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's equpped with USB-C, mini HDMI, audio in and audio out ports. I'm guessing that they don't see this as a studio camera as many might have expected from them, but rather a more portable medium format.

Comment: I was wondering about the omission. I don't think a more portable camera (relatively compact and lightweight) is in contradiction to studio use, though. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's not a contradiction, but generally not what people would necessarily gravitate to in that setting.

Comment: isn't there hot-shoe-PC adapters? PC socket is used to trigger flash/strobe, correct?

Comment: @aaaaaa - yep, I have one. Pretty inexpensive.

Comment: plus, PC socket is being replaced by wireless controllers, i guess. So its presence has little to do with studio usage

Comment: PC is still used a lot, though